# Prove that a bilinear form is nondegenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $V=\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $$f(A,B)=n\mathrm{Tr}(AB) - \mathrm{Tr}(A)\mathrm{Tr}(B).$$ Let $$W=\{ A\in V\, |\, \mathrm{Tr}(A)=0 \} $$ and let $f_1=f|_{W}$.

Prove that $f_1$ is nondegenerate.

---

What I have done:
We have that $\mathrm{Tr}(A)=\mathrm{Tr}(B)=0 $, then $f_1(A,B)=n\mathrm{Tr}(AB)$. We have to prove that: $n\mathrm{Tr}(A,B)=0 \; \forall \beta \in W $ implies $A=0$. But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is $f_1(A, ^t\overline{A})$?

Comment: I assume you meant to write the $t$ superscript after the comma. The transpose of $A$ ($A^{t}$) would still belong to W, and we can say the same for $\overline{A}$. But I'm not sure what can we say about the product. I don't think the trace of the product would be zero.

Comment: I meant: "I assume you meant to write the superscript _before_ the comma"

Comment: I used my native country notation. So it is the trace of the matrix product of $A$ and the transpose of $\overline{A}$. When you write it explicitly, you get $\sum_{i,j}{|A_{i,j}|^2}$.

Comment: I see, so that would be greater than zero for every non-zero A. But I'm not sure of how to proceed after that.

Comment: Do you remember the definition of “nondegenerate”?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondegenerate_form): $f(x,y)=0 \; \forall y$ implies $x=0$

Comment: I think I solved it, but I did not use the fact that that $Tr(A)=Tr(B)=0$ , except for the first step, written in my original question. Is it still possible I did it right? I concluded, that, in general, the function $f=Tr(A)Tr(B)$ is nondegenerate, regardless of whether the trace is zero or not. Is that correct?

Comment: No: if the trace of $A$ is zero, then for all $B$, $Tr(A)Tr(B)=0$...